# Document Frequency and Null Values in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, searchkick

I have an app that uses the following elasticsearch autocomplete query to allow users to search for products based on the product name and it's alternate names.

```
        "query": {
          "dis_max": {
            "queries": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "name.autocomplete": {
                    "query": "p",
                    "analyzer": "autocomplete_search",
                    "boost": 3
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "alternate_names",
                  "score_mode": "max",
                  "query": {
                    "match": {
                      "alternate_names.name.autocomplete": {
                        "query": "p",
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
```

All products have a name but only about 10% of products have an alternate name (stored as a nested field under products). Even though I am boosting matches on name over matches on alternate name, I noticed that sometimes after typing one letter, it would return a match on alternate name over a match on name.

After doing some digging with the explain API, I discovered that this is happening because the calculation for document frequency for alternate names is using the number of matching documents / the total number of documents (as expected). However, the results are skewed in this case because so many products have a null alternate name. So if 10% of products have that includes a word beginning with 'p', and 10% of alternate names have a word beginning with 'p', the query believes the match on the alternate name to be much more relevant because only 1% of all products have an alternate name beginning with 'p'.

I'm wondering if anyone has run into this issue and knows a way to address it? Ideally, I would like to not count documents with null alternate names for the total doc count in the document frequency calculation for matches on alternate name. Or, I could use the same tf/idf calculation across both fields so that alternate names are just seen as other names in terms of how unique a specific word is. However, I have not been able to figure out how to do either or these things.